# Mock Patch raising error TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to unittest my code, and am using a mock function to raise an exception. For which I am using @patch decorator from the mock class, and using side_effect to raise the error. However, I am getting an error whose reason I am not able to figure out.

My Code:

```py
# Test class to test the wiki_parser.
class TestParseWiki(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        return super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        return super().tearDown()

    @patch('parse_wiki.parse_wiki_info', return_value=(1808130, ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_programming_language', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel_programming_language']))
    def test_valid_case(self, mock_parse_wiki_info):
        valid_wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=SMALL&prop=revisions&rvprop=content'
        self.assertEqual(
            mock_parse_wiki_info(valid_wiki_url),
            (1808130, ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_programming_language', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel_programming_language'])
        )

    @patch('parse_wiki.parse_wiki_info', side_effect=FailedRequestException('Failed to complete request. Kindly retry later.'))
    def test_failed_request_case(self):
        invalid_wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=SMALL&rvprop=content'
        with self.assertRaises(FailedRequestException) as e:
            parse_wiki_info(invalid_wiki_url)
        self.assertEqual(
            str(e.exception), "Failed to complete request. Kindly retry later."
        )
```

I am getting the following error:

```bash
=============================================================================== ERRORS ================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_parse_wiki.py _________________________________________________________________
test_parse_wiki.py:7: in <module>
    class TestParseWiki(unittest.TestCase):
test_parse_wiki.py:38: in TestParseWiki
    @patch('parse_wiki.parse_wiki_info', FailedRequestException('Failed to complete request. Kindly retry later.'))
E   TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
======================================================================= short test summary info =======================================================================
ERROR test_parse_wiki.py - TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================================================================== 1 error in 0.18s ===========================================================================
```

Kindly ignore the line numbers, I haven't added some test cases here.
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What does ```parse_wiki.parse_wiki_info``` look like?

Comment: It's a parser function. A sample valid response is ```1808130 ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_programming_language', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel_programming_language']```

Comment: Please note. It returns 2 values (int, list[str])

Comment: Can you please show `FailedRequestException` class definition? Or check whether its __init__ method accepts 2 params or not.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
parse_wiki_info(invalid_wiki_url)
```

the variable `parse_wiki_info` holds a reference to the original `parse_wiki.parse_wiki_info` and does not get changed when `parse_wiki.parse_wiki_info`, an attribute of the `parse_wiki` module object, gets reassigned by `patch` to a `Mock` object.

Instead, you should import `parse_wiki` as a module object and reference `parse_wiki_info` as its attribute so that you can test the updated references to the `Mock` object:

```
import parse_wiki

...

with self.assertRaises(FailedRequestException) as e:
    parse_wiki.parse_wiki_info(invalid_wiki_url)
```